# jquery 1.9 multi checkbox validate

Tags: jquery

this is my old code, but with jquery 1.9 doens't work.

```
var interested = new Array();

$("input[name=interest]:checkbox:checked").each(function(i) {

        interested.push($(this).attr("class"));

});
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What doesn't work?  What does this code do?  Not do?  What do you want it to do?

Comment: :) it's ok now..take it easy man

Answer (score 0):

How about try:

```
var interested = [];

$('input[name=interest]:checked').each(function () {
    interested.push($(this).attr('class');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qT4JW/)

Answer (score 0):

try this code [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/qT4JW/1/)

```
var interested = [];

  $("input[name='interest'][type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {

    interested.push($(this).attr("class"));
 });
```

Comment: What about the `name=interest`?

Comment: So why does it fail in 1.9? Have they altered the selector syntax/logic?

Comment: @til_b If you are using < IE 8, that's one reason it may not work.